# Python PIL bitmap/png from array with mode=1

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Playing with PIL (and numpy) for the first time ever. I was trying to generate a black and white checkerboard image through mode='1', but it doesn't work.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = np.asarray(dtype=np.dtype('uint8'), a=[
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ],
    ])
    print(g)

    i = Image.fromarray(g, mode='1')
    i.save('checker.png')
```

Sorry browser is probably going to try to interpolate this, but it is an 8x8 PNG.
[image]

What am I missing?

Relevant PIL docs: https://pillow.readthedocs.org/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes

```
$ pip freeze
numpy==1.9.2
Pillow==2.9.0
wheel==0.24.0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There seem to be issues when using mode `1` with numpy arrays. As a workaround you could use mode `L` and convert to mode `1` before saving. The below snippet produces the expected checkerboard.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = np.asarray(dtype=np.dtype('uint8'), a=[
        [0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255],
        [255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0],
        [0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255],
        [255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0],
        [0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255],
        [255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0],
        [0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255],
        [255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0]
    ])
    print(g)

    i = Image.fromarray(g, mode='L').convert('1')
    i.save('checker.png')
```

Comment: Yeah I got grayscale mode to work in this way. The convert from there seems to work for me as well. I guess '1' mode still uses a whole byte to contain each bit (at least the documentation intends that), so it's not too different in terms of system resources. So this seems fine for now.

Comment: This works, however, `Image.frombytes(mode='1', size=data.shape[::-1], data=np.packbits(data, axis=1))` is roughly 2x faster than `Image.fromarray(data * 255, mode='L').convert('1')`

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the other answer, you are running into a Pillow bug, and the accepted answer is fine.

As an alternative to PIL/Pillow, you could use [`pypng`](https://pypi.org/project/pypng/), or you could use `numpngw`, a library that I wrote to write NumPy arrays to PNG and animated PNG files.  It is on github: https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/numpngw (It has all the boilerplate files of a python package, but the essential file is `numpngw.py`.)  It is also on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/numpngw/).

Here's an example of using `numpngw.write_png` to create the checkerboard image.  This creates an image with bit depth *1*:

```
In [10]: g
Out[10]: 
array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]], dtype=uint8)

In [11]: import numpngw

In [12]: numpngw.write_png('checkerboard.png', g, bitdepth=1)
```

Here's the image it creates:

[image: 8x8 checkerboard]

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a bug. It has been reported [on Github](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/350). Although some [fix has been commited](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/347#issuecomment-25340007), it seems that it didn't resolve this problem. Everything works fine if you use mode "L" and then convert image to mode "1", so you can use it as a workaround for your problem:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = np.asarray(dtype=np.dtype('uint8'), a=[
        [0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, ],
        [255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, ],
        [0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, ],
        [255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, ],
        [0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, ],
        [255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, ],
        [0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, ],
        [255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, ],
    ])
    print(g)

    i = Image.fromarray(g, mode='L').convert('1')
    i.save('checker.png')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [PyPNG](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypng):

```
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = np.asarray(dtype=np.dtype('uint8'), a=[
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ],
    ])
    print(g)

    import png
    i = png.from_array(g, mode='L;1')
    i.save('checker.png')
```