# 1 Bit Image creation PIL.Image fromarray error

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

```
mypixels = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
im = Image.fromarray(mypixels.astype('bool'), '1')
```

Trying to generate a 1 Bit TIFF file through above code, but it gives wrong result.
Anybody tried this is it working?

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong with your result ? What is the expected result ?

Comment: we expect image with black and white pixel in first row and white and black pixle in second row but getting total black image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python PIL bitmap/png from array with mode=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159076/python-pil-bitmap-png-from-array-with-mode-1) See the GitHub issue links there, and the future discussions on GitHub. It seems, this bug is still not resolved, even in Pillow 6.2.1.

Comment: I manged this with  im = PIL.Image.fromarray(I)  im.mode = "1" but i am getting only 70 DPI resolution which i am editing a Image with 1270x1270 DPI