# Encryption Research Project Assistance

Tags: python, file-upload

So I am currently working on a research project in python that simulates a new encryption method. I am trying to test how well it works by using image files (JPEG, PNG, etc.), specifically ones with different ratios of 0 and 1 bits (e.g. a file with 70% 0 bits and 30% 1 bits). However, I am struggling with finding image files with such ratios anywhere on the internet.

Are there any particular ways to generate image files of my own using certain techniques that I could use to test out how effectively my encryption method works?

Comment: If you want to provide an example without finding a complex image, you might want to try drawing a simple black and white pixel-art image with those ratios yourself, with 1s and 0s representing white and black respectively

Comment: be ssure yo have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159076/python-pil-bitmap-png-from-array-with-mode-1 , ....There seem to be issues when using mode 1 with numpy arrays. As a workaround you could use mode L and convert to mode 1 before saving.....

Answer (score 1):

```
from PIL import Image,ImageOps

import numpy as np


arr = np.zeros((100,100)).astype('uint8')


for  y in range(arr.shape[0]*30//100):
    for x in range(arr.shape[1]*30//100):
        arr[y,x] = 255


print(arr)



img = Image.fromarray(arr, 'L')

img = ImageOps.invert(img).convert('1')  # convert to '1' needed as per comment above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159076/python-pil-bitmap-png-from-array-with-mode-1

img.show()

img.save('test.png')
```

output file:

```
test.png: PNG image data, 100 x 100, 1-bit grayscale, non-interlaced
```